# What is Color.web("0x0001FF", 1.0) and why i'm getting blue color in background?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new in `JavaFx` but have good knowledge in Java. Now basically I'm learning at the moment with this program:

```
package com.lesson;

import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;

public class MyProgram extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        primaryStage.setTitle("My anme is rajedra");

        Group group=new Group();
        Scene s=new Scene(group, 400, 400, Color.web("0x0001FF", 1.0));
        TitledPane tp1=new TitledPane("T1", new Button("B1"));
        TitledPane tp2=new TitledPane("T2", new Button("b2"));
        TitledPane tp3=new TitledPane("T3", new Button("b3"));
        TitledPane tp4=new TitledPane("T4", new Button("b4"));

        Accordion accordion=new Accordion();
        accordion.getPanes().addAll(tp1, tp2, tp3);
        group.getChildren().add(accordion);
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

But don't understand exactly what `Color.web("0x0001FF", 1.0)` here? I found background color shows `Blue` After running this program. But I haven't typed any `blue` or any `Code` which tends to show. Now what's that mean here please help.

Help would be appreciated! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a color defined by the hex `0001FF`, with 100% (1.0) opacity.

> Why is it blue?

Because a hex colour is written like this:

```
00      01      FF
^^      ^^      ^^
RED    GREEN   BLUE
```

In decimal, `00` is `0`, `FF` is `255`.

In RGB, every colour value can go from `0` (no colour) to `255` (full colour).

So you are filling it with 255 blue (100%), 1 Green (which slightly modifies the blue, there is almost no visual difference) and 0 red.

Comment: Okay..thanks for answering and what is `1.0` here with `Color.web("0x0001FF", 1.0)`.

Comment: @nitinsharma It's written in the first line, 1.0 means 100% opacity.

Answer (score 1):

Check the relevant [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#web-java.lang.String-double-).

First parameter of the `Color.web()` method is the RGB (Red, Green, Blue) value of the color.

```
"0x0001FF"
```

This has `0x00` red component, `0x01` green component (almost zero) and full `0xff` blue component.

The second parameter of the `Color.web()` is the opacity in the range from `0.0` (transparent) to `1.0` (opaque, this is your case).

Therefore your result color is blue.

Comment: Okay..thanks for answering and what is `1.0` here with `Color.web("0x0001FF", 1.0)`.

Comment: It's included in the answer, please read the whole answer before copy-pasting comments to all answers.

Answer (score 1):

`0x0001ff` is a hex-representation of a color in `RGB`: 1 byte per color component.
So it's

`0x00` (0/255) for Red

`0x01` (1/255) for Green

`0xff` (255/255) for Blue.

That's why it's blue.

`1.0` stays for opacity. `0.0` is completely transparent, `1.0` is opaque. You can specify any value in between.

Answer (score 0):

0001FF is the hex code for blue: http://www.colorhexa.com/0001ff

Thus, you background appears to be blue.

Comment: Okay..thanks for answering and what is `1.0` here with `Color.web("0x0001FF", 1.0)`.

Comment: that's the opacity: if that number were lower, the color would be more transparent. Check the javadoc.